# The same log messages on every startup. I need to understand what they mean

Tags: security, logs, 22.10

When I check my logs in the "important" tab, they are pretty much the same on every startup. Is there something concerning about them? For example, what are these issues labeled as "security"? Are they something usual or a potential security vulnerability?

**Edit:** Additional info about failed to start Application:

> A start job for unit UNIT has finished with a failure.
>
> The job identifier is 452 and the job result is failed.

The other messages are the same but the identifiers are 440 and 436.

[image]

Comment: it's just unable to start snapd service( which is a serviice to run snap apps like firefox and etc....) and gnome certain apps. Plus ate the 2nd last line states that it is unable to read the filesystem(either it's corrupt or not a supported file system).

Comment: These are really 7 separate questions. I would look into the two questions labeled Security. Two processes failed to start: are they still not running at this time? (They may have been successfully started later in the boot process.) Are they actually necessary? You may search this site for the exact error messages, and if still in doubt, ask a separate question.